# what is Android Context and why is it needed

Tags: android, android-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

I would like to know what exactly Android's Context is, and why it is needed. I know it's related to class and each class has a unique context. I have seen in some code which passes a Context when calling methods of another class. I don't understand why it is needed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

a Context is:

> Interface to global information about
>   an application environment. This is an
>   abstract class whose implementation is
>   provided by the Android system. It
>   allows access to application-specific
>   resources and classes, as well as
>   up-calls for application-level
>   operations such as launching
>   activities, broadcasting and receiving
>   intents, etc.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 1):

All classes does not have an android context. Their is an application context, and activity c contexts. A context is used for a lot of things, but most often it is just to load and access resources.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The android context holds information about your application's environment.

You might want to take a look at the official [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) in order to understand which information is being held by your context and what operations you can do with it.